# How to insert literal into register using asm function in .c file

Tags: c, assembly

I am getting a segmentation fault error with the current code. I have tried many different variations of changing [edx]/edx/%[edx]/[%edx] with no success. I want to set edx register contents to null. This is a .c file using gcc. Intel processor on linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    asm("mov %edx, /0");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you do `movl $0, %edx` instead?  And I think you should also tell GCC that you have clobbered EDX.

Comment: There is no such instruction mov1 for my current setup or that may be for a different function

Comment: The last character is lowercase L.

Comment: I might suggest xor %edx, %edx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing AT&T syntax (as used in gcc) with the Intel syntax where the first register is the destination. Have a look at this page:

http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

```
+------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|       Intel Code             |      AT&T Code                     |
+------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| mov     eax,1                |  movl    $1,%eax                   |   
| mov     ebx,0ffh             |  movl    $0xff,%ebx                |   
| int     80h                  |  int     $0x80                     |   
| mov     ebx, eax             |  movl    %eax, %ebx                |
| mov     eax,[ecx]            |  movl    (%ecx),%eax               |
| mov     eax,[ebx+3]          |  movl    3(%ebx),%eax              | 
| mov     eax,[ebx+20h]        |  movl    0x20(%ebx),%eax           |
| add     eax,[ebx+ecx*2h]     |  addl    (%ebx,%ecx,0x2),%eax      |
| lea     eax,[ebx+ecx]        |  leal    (%ebx,%ecx),%eax          |
| sub     eax,[ebx+ecx*4h-20h] |  subl    -0x20(%ebx,%ecx,0x4),%eax |
+------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you I had the order mixed up